# How to see/expand all the values returned in a variable?

Tags: powershell

I want to just spit out the values/fields/objects/whatever they're called used in the dot notation when you append to variables.

I'm not sure I'm using the right terms here, but the goal is this:

When pulling information, such as a web API request and storing as a variable, I need to filter out information down to what I need. That consist of me running code, getting output, finding the options to drill down with dot notation and trying again and again until I have what I want.

Sample:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile"
```

returns something like:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xml:lang="en"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:Web="http://schemas.live.com/Web/"><script     type="text/javascript" >//<![CDATA[
                si_ST=new Date
                //]]></script><h...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                Pragma: no-cache
                Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
                Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                Expires: -1
                P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC...
Forms             : {sb_form}
```

I know that if assigned the Invoke-Webrequest to a variable, i could do $variable.StatusCode...or $Variable.RawContent to further filter out what I'm looking for. Is there anyway just to get back the values like StatusCode, StatusDescription, Content, etc without getting all the data that comes along with it? What is the proper term for these things?

Comment: Pipe your output to select-object —> `select-object statuscode,content`

Comment: ok, but how did I know those were options before seeing the output?

Comment: @dcvl - you need to either explore the object or know it from some other source. [*grin*] you may want to look at something like the `powershell object browser` for a fairly easy visual way to explore objects.

Comment: If you just want to display all properties/values to the user do `... | Format-List *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, you can view specific properties and their values using [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6). The `-Property` parameter supports an array input so you can just comma-separate the properties you want to view. This returns a `[PSCustomObject]`.

```
$response | Select-Object -Property StatusCode,StatusDescription
```

If you only want to see property values without seeing the property names, you can access the property values directly and then format appropriately. For example, to list `StatusCode` and `StatusDescription` values one line at a time, you can do the following:

```
$response.StatusCode,$response.StatusDescription
```

If you want them formatted tab delimited, you can do the following:

```
$response.StatusCode,$response.StatusDescription -join "`t"
```

---

A PowerShell object will have a set of properties and associated values to access. The `Invoke-WebRequest` command you have executed happens to return a `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject]` object.

You can determine your object type using the `GetType()` method. The syntax is `$object.GetType()` or `$object.GetType().FullName`.

If you already have an object, you can use the `.` (dereferences operator) to access a property value using the syntax `$object.property`. That retrieves the property value as the type that is stored in that property. `Property1` could be an `[int]`, and `Property2` could be a `[string]`.

You can view properties available to your object by piping to [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6) or view the properties and their values by piping to [Format-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-6). `Format-List *` displays all properties. `Format-List Property1,Property2` displays only two properties.

```
# Examples
$response | Get-Member
$response | Format-List *
```

Some object types have static properties and methods, which means they don't require instantiation to be accessible. For example, you can view a `[string]`'s static members using `Get-Member -Static`:

```
[string] | Get-Member -Static
```

For objects that require instantiation, you will have to create the object first. Some classes have constructors that will allow you to utilize the static method `New()` or `New-Object` to create an object. You have to be mindful if the constructor requires parameters. Running certain commands will output an object type from where you can access properties and methods similar to your current situation.

```
# To List String's Definitions For New
[string]::new

# Create a New String Following a Definition string new(char[] value)
[string]::new(('h','i'))
```